# How to reference modules each other in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using the aws with terraform. There are 2 modules(KMS, IAM) and they are references each other principles like below.

KMS policy

```
statement {
  sid = "Allow access for Key Administrators"
  effect = "Allow"
  actions = [
      "kms:*"
  ]
  resources = [ "*", ]
  principals {
    type        = "AWS"
    **identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/rolename"]**
  }
}
```

IAM role policy

```
statement {
  effect = "Allow"
  actions = [
    "kms:Decrypt"
  ]
  **resources = [
    "${var.source_kms_arn}"
  ]**
  condition {
    test     = "StringLike"
    variable = "kms:ViaService"

    values = ["s3.region.amazonaws.com"]
  }
  condition {
    test     = "StringLike"
    variable = "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:s3:arn"

    values = [ for bucket_name in var.bucket_names : "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}/*" ]
  }
}
```

But, when i apply in terraform i get error like below.

```
policy: MalformedPolicyDocumentException: Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals.
```

I know there is no IAM role when create kms,
how can i set iam role arn in KMS policy?

Best regards.

Comment: Wait, you want to create the IAM role based on the IAM policy and reference it in the KMS policy?

Comment: @MarkoE yes, i want to reference each other in terraform.

Comment: I think that would create a circular dependency.

Comment: @MarkoE thank you for your reply. I will check about circular dependency.